# Show that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} {\frac{n^s}{(1+p)^n}} = 0$ without using Ratio test.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> **Problem:** Let $s>0$, $p>0$. Show that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} {\displaystyle\frac{n^s}{(1+p)^n}} = 0$.

I can prove this problem by using Ratio test. But is there another way to prove this without using Ratio test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First show it is in indeterminate form, then apply l'Hopital's rule

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^s}{(1+p)^n}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{sn^{s-1}}{(1+p)^n\ln(1+p)}=\frac{s}{\ln(1+p)}\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{s-1}}{(1+p)^n}$$

Keep applying L'Hopital's rule $n-1$ times, you will end up with a constant times $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{(1+p)^n}$.  Just note that the constant is some power of $\frac{s}{\ln(1+p)}$ which is always a constant, so the whole expression will be $0$ as $n \to \infty$

Comment: So, L'Hopital's rule is a is a tools to solve sequences with indeterminate forrm

Comment: It uses derivatives to help evaluate limits involving indeterminate forms. Application (or repeated application) of the rule often converts an indeterminate form to an expression that can be evaluated by substitution, allowing easier evaluation of the limit.

Answer (score 1):

You want a "direct proof" of it. Since the denominator is way larger than the numerator, you might want to involve squeeze theorem and try to establish the ...fact that: $\dfrac{n^s}{(1+p)^n} < \dfrac{1}{n}\implies (1+p)^n > n^{s+1}\iff n > a\ln n$ whereas $a > 0$ is a constant in terms of $p,s$. But you can write $n = e^{\ln n}  > 1 + \ln n + \dfrac{(\ln n)^2}{2}\implies n > \dfrac{(\ln n)^2}{2} > a\ln n$ when $n > e^{2a}$. Thus the inequality is validated and squeeze theorem goes through...

Comment: You knew what i want. But I don't know why $\dfrac{n^s}{(1+p)^n} < \dfrac{1}{n}$. Are we need to prove this?

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=\frac{n^s}{(1+p)^n}$. Then $a_n^{1/n} \to \frac{1}{1+p}$. Since $p>0$ there is $q$ such that $\frac{1}{1+p}<q<1$. Hence there is $N$ with

$a_n^{1/n}<q$ for all $n>N$. Hence

$0<a_n<q^n$ for all $n>N$, which gives the assertion.

Answer (score 1):

$s=1:$ For $n>2,$ apply the binomial theorem in the denominator to get

$$\frac{n}{(1+p)^n} = \frac{n}{1+np + n(n-1)p^2/2 + \cdots } < \frac{n}{n(n-1)p^2/2}\to 0.$$

Now for any $s>0,$ we have $(1+p)^{1/s} > 1,$ which implies $(1+p)^{1/s} = 1+q$ for some $q>0.$ Thus the $s=1$ result implies

$$\frac{n^s}{(1+p)^n} = \left (\frac{n}{[(1+p)^{1/s}]^n}\right)^s  = \left (\frac{n}{(1+q)^n}\right)^s \to 0^s = 0.$$